# add parameters to select case db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have following select statement:

```
 select (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'     
             when age_years < 50 then '30-49'                               
             when age_years < 70 then '50-69'                               
              when age_years < 100 then '70-100'                            
             end) as age_range, count(*) as num                             
         from INFO                                          
       group by (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'  
          when age_years < 50 then '30-49'                                  
          when age_years < 70 then '50-69'                                  
          when age_years < 100 then '70-100'                                
          end)                                                              
          order by min(age_years);
```

Output

```
 AGE_RANGE          NUM   
---------+---------+-----
18-29              828   
30-49             2510   
50-69             2014   
70-100             649
```

Now I want to add a column with a percentage of male/female parameter "GENDER" (0 or 1) in "INFO" and with a parameter of another table "PAYTB", the sum of all transactions  "ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT". Both tables share CONT_ID.
It should look like this:

```
 AGE_RANGE          NUM      GENDER       Transaction amount average
---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------
18-29              828        50%         2000 $
30-49             2510        ??          ??? 
50-69             2014        ??          ???
70-100             649
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do it for you. Basically you are just adding too more aggregates. I changed your Counts, because I assumed there was a 1 to Many relationship between the new table and the client table.

```
 select (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'     
             when age_years < 50 then '30-49'                               
             when age_years < 70 then '50-69'                               
              when age_years < 100 then '70-100'                            
             end) as age_range, 
             count(DISTINCT <PK_CLIENT_INFO>) as num ,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CLIENT_INFO = 'MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(DISTINCT <PK_CLIENT_INFO>) 'Male/Female'
             ,SUM(ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT) / COUNT(*) 'TOTAL-Amount Avg'
         from INFO c
         left paytb t
         on c.CONT_ID = t.CONT_ID                                          
       group by (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'  
          when age_years < 50 then '30-49'                                  
          when age_years < 70 then '50-69'                                  
          when age_years < 100 then '70-100'                                
          end)                                                              
          order by min(age_years);
```

Comment: I have problems with this line
 CASE WHEN GENDER = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END / COUNT(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID) 'Male/Female'

Comment: @bastel sorry about that, it should be surrounded by a SUM() so it adds 1 for each male or each female depending on what a value of 1 represents.